# Rails 4 Devise Seed Users with random passwords

Tags: mysql, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, seeding

I've installed Devise in an existing app and need to seed the database with 100 users. They now have the fields that Devise added, such as email and encrypted_password, etc. The part of the seed file that I'm trying is this:
(seeds.rb...)

```
    users = [] # Empty array to store users
    100.times do
        username = "#{Faker::Vehicle.make}#{Faker::BaconIpsum.word}-#{rand(999)}"
        user_password = SecureRandom.base64(12)
        u = User.new
            u.id = SecureRandom.random_number(9999999999)
            u.username = username.gsub(/\s+/,"")
            u.password = user_password
            u.password_confirmation = user_password
            u.email = "#{Faker::Internet.free_email}"
            u.sign_in_count = 0
       u.save
       users << u # Put newly created user in the array
    end
```

Just seeding with the NOT NULL fields. When I try to seed, I get the following error:

> > ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Field 'password' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `encrypted_password`, `id`, `username`) VALUES ('colton@gmail.com', '$2a$10$F9RR6h3R48ySJ3./lrPgfeqE84MgPJh7TVseXL.ngwU1Xp5hYxPDC', 3494734525, 'Mitsubishibrisket-872')

EDIT: the schema.rb for the users table, as generated by migrations...

```
    create_table "users", force: true do |t|
        t.string   "username",               limit: 30,              null: false
        t.string   "password",               limit: 30,              null: false
        t.string   "email",                             default: "", null: false
        t.string   "encrypted_password",                default: "", null: false
        t.string   "reset_password_token"
        t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
        t.datetime "remember_created_at"
        t.integer  "sign_in_count",                     default: 0,  null: false
        t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
        t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
        t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
        t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
     end

     add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
      add_index "users", ["username", "id"], name: "BY_USERNAME", using: :btree
```

Clearly, I'm passing a value for "password" here. Following other postings on SO, etc. I learned to send "password" and "password_confirmation" instead of trying to send "encrypted_password". Still get the same error. Why doesn't this work?
Should I be requiring 'devise' in my seeds.rb file?
Reading the error, it almost seems like I should change "password" field to allow NULL and just store "encrypted" password.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: How does the schema.rb for "users" table look like?

Comment: @dgilperez Updated my post to show the schema.rb for users table

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. What I did was drop the database and go into the migration file where I created the Users table. *Not* the "add_devise_to_users" migration, but the original one. This is where the password field is located. Changed to add a default. It looks like this now...

```
    class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def self.up
        # create USERS table
          create_table "users", id: false, force: true do |t|
            t.integer "id",       limit: 8,  default: 0,  null: false
            t.string  "username", limit: 30, default: "", null: false
            t.string  "password", limit: 30, default: "", null: false   
          end
          execute "ALTER TABLE users ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);"
          add_index "users", ["username", "id"], name: "BY_USERNAME", using: :btree
      end

      def self.down
        drop_table :users
      end
    end
```

As you can see, I also added a default value for the "id" field, because apparently Devise has issues with that. After changing this, ran rake db:create, rake db:migrate, and rake db:seed.

This fixes my problem and I can create users and seed with seeds.rb. At first, it looks like an insecure thing to do - to provide default values for passwords and user id's. But where it is validated for "uniqueness", I guess it's ok.

Comments welcome